# How to model this?

Tags: sql, database, modeling

This is my first time asking here, an in english. Sorry, but my english is not very good.

I am developing a web application, for the monitoring of patients in a hospital, and I'm having problem to model the next:

In the real life, the doctor, fill a form. That one, is like a poll or a survey.

So, there is a patient. He could have one or more surgeries. There are differents types of surgeries. those one could be:

- knee surgery
- hip surgery

But the idea is tho could be flexible and would allow adding new surgeries.

Furthermore, there are 3 different instance for each surgery:

- pre-surgical (before)
- intra-surgical (during)
- post-surgical (after)

I'm trying to developing that in MySQL, but i'm open for new ideas.

If anyone have an idea for modeling that business, i'll be graceful. Thankyou so much for helping me, and one more time sorry for my english.

---

Update!

Last night i model this. I don't know if the best way, im open to any ideas.

[image: model_version_1.0]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like a table of surgery types, a table of actual surgeries for a patient, and a cross-reference table between surgeries and doctors.  (Assuming there can be multiple doctors who perform a surgery.)

```
create table SurgeryTypes
(
    [id] int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    [name] nvarchar(200)
)

create table Doctor -- I assume there is a table like there somewhere
(
    [id] int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    [name] nvarchar(200)
)

create table Patient
(
    [id] int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    [name] nvarchar(200)
)

create table Surgery
(
    [id] int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    [starttime] datetime2,
    [endtime] datetime2,
    [surgerytype_id] int, -- foreign key to SurgeryTypes
    [patient_id] int -- foreign key to Patient table
)

create table SurgeryDoctors
(
    surgery_id int,
    doctor_id int,
    primary key (surgery_id, doctor_id)
)

create table Feedback
(
    [id] int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    [patient_id] int not null, -- FK to Patient
    [date] datetime2,
    [surgery_id] int null, -- FK to Surgery; can be NULL to represent "general" feedback
    [doctor_id] int null, -- FK to Doctor; can be NULL to represent "general" feedback
    [comments] nvarchar(max)
)
```

Note: my experience is with SQL Server.  The code above may be very different for MySql.

Edit: Added a Feedback table.

Comment: I try to resolved like that, but i can't model the poll part.

Comment: I added Feedback table that could represent comments for a specific surgery, specific doctor, or general comments.